# ReactJS: Should a parent component's fetched data be stored in state to pass to children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, view, parent-child, state

When I am in a situation where I need pass a significant size of data to a child component, it seems the easiest way to do this is to store it in state and then pass it to children as props inside the render function. I am wondering if there is a less-intensive way to do this.

For instance, if I have a relationship like so:

```
<PhotosPage>
 <PhotoFeed/>
</PhotosPage>
```

I know that I want to fetch the 'photo feed' data when the `PhotosPage` mounts. Let's say I fetch this data in `PhotoPage`'s `componentDidMount()` function. It seems so obvious to me that after the fetch request is completed to just set state, something like:

```
this.setState({feedData: response.data})
```

And then I can simply pass `this.state.feedData` into the `PhotoFeed` component as a `prop`:

```
<PhotoFeed feedData={this.state.feedData} )}/>
```

This is a very basic example that does not include the rest of the complexity of the component. Is there a less state-intensive way to do this? I'm sure this is a very common container to view relationship and I want to know if there are any 'better' ways to do this without redux,etc. I just worry that I may be using state when I don't have to.

Comment: That's the way to go unless you're using an explicit state management system. Don't worry about it

Comment: Seems ok to me.  This question probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since it's working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally an accepted method, the technique is called container components. [Here](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) is a good write-up about these.

[Here](https://medium.com/gitconnected/react-component-patterns-ab1f09be2c82) is another discussing some different options.